# Can a GraphQL resolver force arguments in parent to be retrieved?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

If I have 2 types: `User` and `Note` with the following schema:

```js
query {
   getUser(userId: ID!): User
}

type User {
   userId: ID
   email: String
   notes: [Note]
}

type Note {
   noteId: ID
   text: String
}
```

I am writing a resolver for `User#notes`. Now say notes need to be retrieved by email address, so I actually need the root object passed to the resolver to contain the `email` field, is there anyway I can force GraphQL to query the `email` field in the `User` object even if the user has not requested it?

In terms of code, from [what I see](https://graphql.org/learn/execution/#trivial-resolvers), this is how I can write a resolver. How can I ensure `obj.email` is requested whenever the user requests the `note` field?

```js
User:  {
  notes(obj, args, context, info) {
    // How can I ensure obj.email is requested?
    return NoteRetriever.getNotesByEmail(obj.email);
  }
}
```

**Edit**

I am wondering about the case where the parent resolver doesn't resolve the `email` field unless explicitly requested. What if we need to make an API call to get the email for the user? So by default we don't request it. However, when the notes is requested, it makes sense to request the email too.

Is there a way for the resolver to specify dependency on parent fields - to ensure that gets requested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the expectation is that if you control the query of the parent, and expect the value in the child, you should ensure the required value is always resolved by the parent.

There is, however, a way to do what you are asking when merging schemas. This is described here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching.

Basically would need to have a base schema that is something like

```
type Query {
    getUser(userId: ID!): User
}

type User {
   userId: ID
   email: String
}
```

With the same resolvers as you have now, and a second schema that is something like

```
type Note {
    noteId: ID
    text: String
}

extend type User {
    notes: [Note]
}
```

Along with something like

```
import { mergeSchemas } from 'graphql-tools';

const finalSchema = mergeSchemas({
    schemas: [userSchema, noteSchema],
    resolvers: {
        User {
            notes: {
                fragment: '... on User { email }',
                resolve: notesResolver
            }
        }
    }
});
console.dir(await graphql(finalSchema, `query { ... }`));
```

Notice the fragment property defining the email field. In the link above it describes how this will force resolution of the given field on the parent when this child is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I came across this as well. And yes, this is what I wanted, but seems like this can only happen when doing schema stitching and not in plain resolver definitions.

Comment: You're 100% right it can only happen during stitching, which is a painful amount of overhead

Answer (score 3):

The "parent" value passed to your resolver as the first parameter is exactly what was returned in the parent field's resolver (unless a Promise was returned, in which case it will be whatever the Promise resolved to). So if we have a resolver like this:

```
Query: {
  getUser: () => {
    return {
      userId: 10,
      email: 'user@example.com',
      foobar: 42,
    }
  }
}
```

and a query like:

```
query {
  getUser {
    id
    notes
  }
}
```

What's passed to our `notes` resolver is the entire object we returned inside the resolver for `getUser`.

```
User:  {
  notes(obj, args, context, info) {
    console.log(obj.userId) // 10
    console.log(obj.email)  // "user@example.com"
    console.log(obj.foobar) // 42
  }
}
```

The parent value will be the same, regardless of the fields requested, unless the parent field resolver's logic actually returns a different value depending on the requested fields. This means you can also pass down any number of other, arbitrary entries (like `foobar` above) from the parent to each child field.

EDIT:

Fields are resolved independently of one another, so there is no mechanism for declaring dependencies between fields. If the `getUser` resolver is looking at the requested fields and making certain API calls based on requested fields (and omitting others if those fields were not requested), then you'll need to modify that logic to account for the `notes` field needing the `user` email.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am wondering about the case where the parent resolver doesn't resolve the email field unless explicitly requested. What if we need to make an API call to get the email for the user? So by default we don't request it. However, when the `notes` is requested, it makes sense to request the `email` too.

Comment: You'll need to handle that logic inside the `getUser` resolver. See my edit.